# change value in javascript method

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this.

I'm trying to create an onclick event that will toggle a value in a method. I'm using OpenSeadragon and I have this currently set as the onclick:

```
viewer.world.getItemAt(1).setOpacity(0);
```

When I press a button in my html, I need the setOpacity(0) to toggle between 0 and 1. This will reveal a layer I have set up in OpenSeadragon. The layer is reflected in the .getItemAt(1). Here is the link to the page with the code: http://web.stanford.edu/~cmalex/woel.

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable = no">
    <title>Wonder of Everyday Life</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1 class="museum">Cantor Arts Center</h1>
    <h1><a href="javascript:history.go(0)" class="show">Restart</a></h1>
</div>    

<div id="subheader">
    <h2>The Wonder of Everyday Life</h2>
    <p>Dutch Golden Age Prints</p>
</div>

<div id="openseadragon"></div>

<div id="instructions">
    <p>Pinch and Zoom or use controls</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div id="toolbar">
        <a id="zoom_in" href="#zoom_in"></a> 
        <a id="zoom_out" href="#zoom_out"></a>
        <a id="reset" href="#reset"></a> 
        <a id="view" onclick="viewer.world.getItemAt(1).setOpacity(0);"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="scripts/openseadragon.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
        id: "openseadragon",
        prefixUrl: "scripts/images/",
        tileSources: "openseadragon/map.dzi",
        opacity: 1,
        zoomInButton: "zoom_in",
        zoomOutButton: "zoom_out",
        homeButton: "reset",
        showNavigator:  true,
        navigatorPosition: "ABSOLUTE",
        navigatorTop:      "10px",
        navigatorLeft:     "10px",
        navigatorHeight:   "145px",
        navigatorWidth:    "125px",
        visibilityRatio: 1.0,
        constrainDuringPan: true
    });

    viewer.addTiledImage({
        tileSource: "openseadragon/overlay.dzi",
        index: 1
    });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: share code to explain your problem

Comment: please write out your onclick event that you have created and any errors you get in your console when you click it. Also by layer do you mean overlay?

Comment: Hi @Akshaypadwal. I have updated the code above. Thanks for your help. Let me know if you need anymore info!

Comment: Hi @Icewine. Code updated above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: what error are you getting in the console?

Comment: @cmalexander You can simply fetch the current opacity of that element and use `(i) ? 0 :1`
Trivial: add Math.floor()

Comment: There is no error. I need setOpacity(0) to change to setOpacity(1) on button click. And vice versa when clicked again.

Comment: Not sure what happened, but I had specified in the post that I was new to JavaScript and then it was gone. I have added it back to the original post.

Comment: have you tried what @unknOwn said?

Comment: @cmalexander This snippet is working in console. `viewer.world.getItemAt(1).setOpacity((viewer.world.getItemAt(1).getOpacity())?0:1);` in your link. Make sure you place it properly and dont have `one` or `off` events in your code.

Comment: Nope. New to JavaScript. Have no idea what "Trivial: add Math.floor()" means. I know it's a function, but not sure where it should reside.

Comment: @unkn0wn are you saying that the <a id="view" onclick="viewer.world.getItemAt(1).setOpacity(0);"></a> should be replaced with <a id="view" onclick="viewer.world.getItemAt(1).setOpacity((viewer.world.getItemAt‌​(1).getOpacity())?0:‌​1);"></a>?

Answer (score 0):

Dont be a lazy bum and Type that snippet in your code. HAHA I noticed some special characters in your site sourcceode `&zwnj;&#8203` when you inserted that snippet.

```
viewer.world.getItemAt(1).setOpacity((viewer.world.getItemAt‌​(1).getOpacity())?0:‌​1)
```

This will get the current value of Opacity of your element `viewer.world.getItemAt‌​(1).getOpacity()` and will display opposite of it `(i)?0:1`.

I asked to use Math.floor(i) because opacity is a decimal value and in case u run into values like`0.8` u can round it off to `0` as you want to dissapear the element. Although its not necessary in your code.

Change

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="toolbar">
        <a id="zoom_in" href="#zoom_in"></a> 
        <a id="zoom_out" href="#zoom_out"></a>
        <a id="reset" href="#reset"></a> 
        <a id="view" onclick="viewer.world.getItemAt(1).setOpacity(0);"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="toolbar">
        <a id="zoom_in" href="#zoom_in"></a> 
        <a id="zoom_out" href="#zoom_out"></a>
        <a id="reset" href="#reset"></a> 
        <a id="view" onclick="viewer.world.getItemAt(1).setOpacity((viewer.world.getItemAt(1).getOpacity())?0:1);"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, you should remove any binding that are restricting the function to be called once like [off](http://api.jquery.com/one/) or [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)
The above solution is working in your site. I checked.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert

Comment: Ha! What do you expect! I'm new to all this! I appreciate the help and the extra effort you put in with me! Ok, so I understand this - is this like an if-then statement in a sense?

Thank you for helping me! It is working exactly like I want it too.

Comment: Care to give the reason for downvote? His site is up n working.

Comment: Yes, it like the shorthand of if else. Generally used for one line condition checking. `(condition)?eventA:eventB` if condition is true eventA is fired, else eventB.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the explanation! I appreciate Stackoverflow as a place to learn. I searched so much to try and figure this out. Everything I found always ended up being more complicated than I thought it would be.

Comment: Good luck! Just remember to follow rules like putting your effort/code with the question, be as clear as you can when asking a question, marking thread closed when you get your solution and stuff like that.